# Log monitoring software whilst developing

Tags: logging, monitoring

We have an enterprise product to monitor our logs in prod/qa.  However am after something to run locally whilst I'm programming/developing to monitor local log files, and pop-up a sys-tray alert (or similar) when an error (or other regex match) appears in a monitored log file.

Would prefer something lightweight and free.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can run [splunk](http://www.splunk.com) locally for free under a certain size of logs and has a great regex ui to slice and dice the entries.